# how do I replace a string with a dollar sign in it in powershell

Tags: powershell

In Powershell given the following string

```
$string = "this is a sample of 'my' text $PSP.what do you think"
```

how do I use the -replace  function to convert the string to

```
this is a sample of 'my' text Hello.what do you think
```

I obviously need to escape the string somehow, Also $PSP is not a declared variable in my script

I need to change all mentions of $PSP for some other string

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the backtick character (above the tab key):

```
$string = "this is a sample of 'my' text `$PSP.what do you think"
```

To replace the dollar sign using the -replace operator, escape it with backslash:

```
"this is a sample of 'my' text `$PSP.what do you think" -replace '\$PSP', 'hello'
```

Or use the string.replace method:

```
$string = "this is a sample of 'my' text `$PSP.what do you think"
$string.Replace('$PSP','Hello)'
```

this is a sample of 'my' text Hello.what do you think

Comment: I can't change in input string

Comment: I'm not following you, where do you get the value from?

Comment: It's from a sql script template, which is loaded into the variable

Comment: Then you shouldn't have a problem replacing the dollar sign with -replace or string.Replace. I can't test with Sql by it works if I read the value from from a text file.

Comment: NB: Also valid is "\`$PSP" instead of '\$PSP'.  When using double quotes as well as escaping the dollar with a backslash (for the regex escaping) you'd need to escape it with a backtick (for the PowerShell escaping).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you modify your original string (e.g. by escaping the $), this is isn't (really) possible.
Your `$string` doesn't really contain a `$PSP`, as it is replaced by nothing in the assignment statement.

```
$string = "this is a sample of 'my' text $PSP.what do you think"
$string -eq "this is a sample of 'my' text .what do you think"
```

evaluates to:

`True`

Comment: This is correct, there is no reason not to  declare  $PSP = "Hello" in the script, which will then produce the desired result
 $string = "this is a sample of 'my' text $PSP.what do you think"

Answer (score 0):

This comes up as the first answer in google even though it is really old, so I will add my slight variation.

In my case I was reading in a file and replacing a string with $s in it.

The short version of my file is:

```
<version>$version$<version>
```

In the case where one is actiong on a (file) stream, variables are not autoreplaced so there is no need to escape the $ in the file.

In the replacement pattern you can avoid the interpretation of the variable using ' instead of ".

My final command looked like:

```
 (gc $fileName) | % { $_.replace('$version$', "$BuildNumber") } | sc  $fileName
```

This is a file read(get-content) piped through the replace and back in to the file with a set-content.

Answer (score -1):

You should try

> $string = $string.Replace("\$PSP", "Hello")

or

> $string = $string.Replace("\$PSP", $the_new_value)

or to be more generic use Regex

> $string = [regex]::Replace($string, "\$\w+", "Hello")

Comment: I could do, but this is a list of chained replaces which would mean changing the format for this single item

Comment: Does this actually work? did you test it? it doesn't work for me

Comment: Yes it works if $string really contain a $ character. When you just check the output. (just $string)  do you see the $PSP or not?